# Reusing ArcObjects code written at 9.3 in ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2

-- update:

i've narrowed down the scope of the question to something more specific in a new question:

[argis 9.3 to arcgis 10.2 arcobjects connection AutomationException: 0x5 - Access is denied. in 'Invoke'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124335/argis-9-3-to-arcgis-10-2-arcobjects-connection-automationexception-0x5-access)

-- end of update.

I have legacy code, written in 9.3. makes extensive use of arcobjects, now the company bought 10.2, and after updating all urls, it turns out that all arcobject calls are no longer supported, and it seems we have to write a server object extension, which is discouraged even in esri's docs,  to wrap the old code.

Am I missing something here? are arcobjects calls really no longer supported in 10? is there a way to reuse the old code that I might be not aware of?

Comment: ArcObjects is very much alive and well, you may be using objects that they have deprecated and you need to seek an alternative object/method.

Comment: Is this specifically regarding ArcObjects with ArcGIS Server?

Comment: Much of the initialization and licensing code has altered in the four major revision gap in your application code.  Many of the interfaces have likely been superseded (and possibly deprecated).  Porting 10.1 code to 10.2 has mostly been a breeze, but the 10.0/10.1 chasm was not tiny.

Answer (score 1):

I also had significant 9.3 code that needed to be upgraded. The good news is that, although some conversion is necessary, it's not difficult.

Firstly you need to get your hands on Visual Studio 2010 if you don't already have it... the Express version works just fine but make sure you're not breaking some licensing restriction by using that version.

Other year versions of Visual Studio *might* work (like 2008, 2012) but I can't hand-on-heart say that. According to the [System Requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000) 2010 professional/express is supported but only 2012 professional is supported (not express).

Next install the SDK from your ArcGis install disk *after* installing Visual Studio.

Read the section about [migrating code](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Migrating_your_code_from_9_3_to_10/000100000ms1000000/).

For almost all of my tools it was just a change of the entry point then copy 'n paste verbatim to update from 9.3 (and 9.2) to 10.1.

More specific help would require knowing what language your code is in and the base class.