# argis 9.3 to arcgis 10.2 arcobjects connection AutomationException: 0x5 - Access is denied. in 'Invoke'

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2

A legacy code, written in 9.3, made connections to the server via the following code

```
public String connect(String domain, String user, String password) {
    new ServerInitializer().initializeServer(domain,  user, password);
    ServerConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = new ServerConnection();
        connection.connect(url);
        return "ok";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }       
}
```

This works fine with a 9.3 server, however, when i try to connect to a 10.2, all i get is:

```
AutomationException: 0x5 - Access is denied. in 'Invoke'
```

Have they changed the way to connect in 10.2, or am i missing something?

Comment: shouldn't that be *IServerConnection connection;*? it's an interface not a class. I can't find any reference to ServerInitializer in Esri objects, is that a Microsoft object?

Comment: hi michael, its java code. ServerConnection implements IServerConnection. Whats strange to me is the fact that i can not find documentation about how to connect to arcobjects in 10.2. The closer i get is arcgis 10.0.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was C# - looks very similar. Connection to a server documentation seems to be a bit sparse, if you're really stuck then post a question (reference this one perhaps) : "How to connect ...." and include the Java tag. I can't help with this - Java really is't my thing.